# Get single column each row difference in SQL Server (alternative of LEAD function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Get single column each row difference in SQL Server.

In my table, `ORIGINAL_DATA` is my current column and want to generate new `EXPECTED_OUTPUT` column with show the difference of each row.

like 40-30 = 10 , 30-25 = 5, 25-10 = 15.

```
SELECT 10 ORIGINAL_DATA,0 EXPECTED_OUTPUT   UNION
SELECT 25, 15  UNION
SELECT 30, 5   UNION
SELECT 40, 10
```

I have used the `LEAD` function but it is not supported by my current version of SQL Server.

So can you please help me to solve this without `LEAD` and `SELF JOIN`?

As my query already taking too much time, here i have mention only sample data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH    rows AS
        (SELECT  Column1 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
         FROM   (
            SELECT 10 Column1 UNION
            SELECT 25 UNION
            SELECT 30 UNION
            SELECT 40
        )M)
SELECT 
--mp.Column1 ,
mc.Column1,
--mc.rn,
--mp.rn,
CAST(mc.Column1 AS float) - CAST(mp.Column1 AS float) EXPECTED_OUTPUT
FROM    rows mc
LEFT JOIN    rows mp
ON   mp.rn = mc.rn - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change SQL Script as per table structure Partition By A and Order By B

```
SELECT  ORIGINAL_DATA, 
ORIGINAL_DATA-LEAD(ORIGINAL_DATA, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B DESC) AS     EXPECTED_OUTPUT   
FROM Table1
```